# How do I integrate this function?

Tags: integration

[image: Question]

I feel like it could be really simple but I'm forgetting something :/.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider that $\cos$ is the derivative of $\sin$.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek you're right ! this is the way +1

Comment: ${1 \over 3} \sin^3(x) + C$

Comment: @Hopeless Then you end up integrating a third power of a trigonometric function which is not that easy.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek isn't the substitution method mentioned below an easier way ?

Comment: @K.M. And why does substitution works here? Exactly because $\cos$ is the derivative of $\sin$...

Comment: @TheGeekGreek oh right, yeah I thought you were going to go down a more complicated path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put $t=\sin(x)$ . then $dt=\cos(x)dx$.

the integral becomes

$$\int \sin^2(x) (\cos(x)dx)=\int t^2dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}t^3+C$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(x)+C$$